# Is it possible to expand rather than simplify a boolean expression?

Tags: boolean, expression, truthtable

I have reached a simplified boolean expression

Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D

and I was wondering if there was any way to expand this expression from its simplified version (how did it get to this current expression)

Comment: Sure, you can! For example, replace C with BC + B'C or replace A with ABD + ABD' + AB'. But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with StackOverflow

Comment: There are infinitely many boolean expressions that reduce to this one.  Which one do you want to find?

Comment: There is no such thing as an irreversible Boolean identity. Of course you can use Boolean algebra to make expressions more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible expand rather than simplify a boolean expression.

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D
```

is, for example, equivalent to this expanded expression:

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D + B.D
```

**No**, it is not possible to recover the original non-simplified form of a boolean expression; that information is not preserved during simplification steps in any way within the simplified expression itself.  This can easily be seen since

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D
```

might have started as

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D + B.D
```

but just as easily could have started as

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D + B.D + B.D
```

or

```
Y = C + A + B'.D' + B.D + B.D + B.D + B.D
```

(You get the idea.)